# HTML file's images not loading in ios app

Tags: html, ios, swift, uialertview

I am working on an app and for the instructions tab, i am using an alertview Controller to display list of options which then the user can select.
Each of the options are attached to an HTML file. All of these work fine except that one of the HTML file have a couple of images and when the app opens that HTML with images, it just shows a square box where the image should be

I have tried loading that image in assets as well as the same folder as the HTML file and when opened normally in a browser the images load fine!
Could anyone provide some insights? thanks in advance!

```
if options == 3 {
            let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Instructions To Record", ofType: "html")
            let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            self.title = "Instructions To Record"
            return htmlString!
        }
  /// html code is below which works fine in Browser
  <p>3) Touch  <img  src="next.png"  > to go to the next page.</p>
```

The sentence should be displaying the image as is as a part of the statement

Comment: `next.png` should be there in the folder where your HTML file is.

Comment: yes ofc i know that and it is in the same folder, i tried in a different folder too with whole path and didnt work, the path is fine since HTML works fine in browser

Answer (score 1):

did you try importing `WEBKIT` in case it  works? i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If the image was in an images subdirectory,then you'd embed it like this:

```
<img src="images/dinosaur.jpg">
```

> You have add image path correctly

Comment: i have tried all of these methods, also including the whole path but now i have placed image in same folder even and still dont work, also it works fine in browser but no luck

Comment: have you added images in image.xcassetes